# C++ calling a static function from another static function

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-functions

have a static function in a header file

```
    class Diagnostics {
    public:


    static void functionA(){
    }

    static void functionB(){
    some code //works fine until enters the loop below
    variable_name // works fine here.
    if (condition){ // 
    variable_name; // after condition is met , i step in here, debugger cannot examine
                   // the vairable_name which was fine above. right after i try to step                      over , i get SIGSEV error
    some_code; // doesnt even come here. Process exited with SIGSEV
    function C(); // tried using classname::functionC , didnt work either

        }
    }

static void functionC(){
}
```

Comment: What's the question? I wouldn't expect `variable_name` to be found - it's not mentioned anywhere in the class definition or in preceding code. And I don't see how the process can exit with SIGSEGV if it doesn't compile, which it won't if `variable_name` isn't found.

Comment: What is `variable_name`? What is `some_code`? Where are they defined? Also you're missing return types on your functions.

Comment: Please show us the exact code.

Comment: Is variable name a non-static class member? if so that's your problem.

Comment: Well, I can't find `variable_name` either...

Comment: This code won't compile. Standard C++ requires functions return type declarations. Though C89 and perhaps some older C++ compilers use `int` as the default return type.

Comment: Also, your definition of `functionC` is *outside* the class, which makes it a non-member function.

Comment: functioC is not outside class. cleaned up code. void return types

Answer (score 4):

`static` inside a `class` means that the member or method in question does not operate on an object, i.e. it doesn't define `this`, but it is still in the class's namespace.

`static` outside a class means what it means in C: the variable or function does not have external linkage, i.e. things outside the current compilation unit cannot link to it.

Two entirely different things.

Comment: Perhaps you were confused because the OP had the code indented incorrectly. I have fixed it, you should see now why this answer doesn't work. (Namely `functionC` is a member of the class)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the problem was. 
Works fine now. initially happened while I was debugging. 
Then i just executed instead of debugging , worked fine.
then i tried debugging again , which worked fine this time.